# postgres select count distinct returning unexpected extra row

Tags: postgresql

If there is one more UID in sessions than there is in users (obviously not supposed to be that way), then I expect to have a non-empty result set when I run the last select, but I get no rows returned - this result just doesn't make logical sense to me...

```
select count(distinct(uid)) from users;

> 108736

select count(distinct(uid)) from sessions;

> 108737

select count(*) from sessions where uid not in (select uid from users);

> 0
```

and just for completeness:

```
select count(*) from users where uid not in (select uid from sessions);

> 0
```

I have checked for nulls:

```
select count( * ) from sessions where uid is null; 

> 0 

select count( * ) from users where uid is null;

> 14
```

The schema is defined in sqlalchemy and includes a foreign key in the session table:

```
uid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.uid', use_alter=True, name='fk_uid'))
```

This schema is a static dump for analytics purposes so there is no chance of concurrency issues...

Comment: Could the mystery uid be 'null' in the session table?

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned that I had tried that - no dice

Comment: no it isn't - as stated I tried that, but thanks @wildplasser

Comment: Just for argument's sake, could you post results of `select count(*) from users where uid is null` and `select count(*) from sessions where uid is null`?

Comment: select count( * ) from sessions where mrn is null; --> 0
select count( * ) from users where mrn is null; --> 14... this is the opposite of what I'd expect if that was the answer as sessions has one more uid than users, but as expected considering the workflow of how the records are created by the program

Comment: Could you show us the schema for the sessions and user tables? I'm not sure what the column `mrn` is in the context of the question, is it the same as `uid`? One way to prevent things like this from happening is to establish constraints (e.g. foreign key constraint on the session table to require a valid uid in the user table, and not null constraints on uid). This could help you identify the problematic data if you can change the schema.

Comment: sorry that was a mistake - mrn == uid (I had renamed the tables in my example to give the simplest possible understanding of how the tables are meant to work...) I'll edit...also there is already a foreign key constraint I'll pop it in a following comment

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment, but it should have been select count( * ) from sessions where uid is null; --> 0 select count( * ) from users where uid is null; --> 14...

Comment: and my schema is defined in sqlalchemy, relevant line in session table:  `uid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.uid', use_alter=True, name='fk_uid'))`

Comment: At this point it'd probably be a lot cleaner if you edited your question to include some of the information from the comments. Specifically that you've looked for nulls, and you have a foreign key constraint between sessions and users.

Comment: What is the data type of `uid`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe int4

Comment: Unrelated but: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. `count(distinct(uid))` is exactly the same thing as `count(distinct  uid)`, and `count distinct (a),b,c` is the same as `count distinct a,b,c` or `count distinct a,b,(c)`

Comment: if `users.uid` can be NULL , it cannot be a primary key (or UNIQUE), so `sessions.uid` cannot be a foreign key to it. [please add the actual DDL to your question]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your third query does not do what you think it does.

The following query illustrates the problem:

```
SELECT 1 NOT IN (SELECT unnest(ARRAY[NULL]::int[]));
```

This returns `NULL`, because it can't say if `1 <> NULL`.
So, in your query the where condition is always `NULL`, because `users` contains a `NULL` uid.

I recommend using `EXCEPT` do find the culprit in your sessions table.

```
SELECT uid from sessions EXCEPT SELECT uid from users;
```